# Can I prevent the word from being dictated when said in isolation in Dragon NaturallySpeaking?

Tags: dragon-naturally-speaking

Can I prevent the word from being dictated when said in isolation in Dragon NaturallySpeaking?

For example, if I say `best`, I don't want Dragon NaturallySpeaking to transcribe "best".

My use case is that I have several voice commands which are named with single words, and when I try to call them Dragon NaturallySpeaking sometimes writes some words that sound similar. E.g., I have a voice command that is named `paste`, but quite often when I say `paste` Dragon NaturallySpeaking will write `best` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some ways to work around ambiguities like this:

1. Create list command.

In Dragon Professional you could alter your single name command to a list of command names. You just put all similar words in the list.
The list would be something like

```
paste
best
beast
```

Just add some more words as needed. All those words would trigger the same command.

In order to convert a list to a command, press the "Name Editor" button in the MyCommands Editor after opening the command. Name the list "paste" or similar, press Insert List and then add the above words.

Here's a YouTube-video explaining it: https://youtu.be/QV0MdezpjBw?t=2m30s (from 2m30s where this part starts)

2. Disable a word by creating a command that does nothing

If you're not into that, you could just create an Advanced Scripting command that does nothing when it recognises "best":

```
Sub Main
SendKeys "" ' Does nothing
End Sub
```

3. Alternatives

You could also use the Vocabulary Editor to disable a word but this would disable it completely. And we don't want that here.